# Vue component doing async hangs at await while jest testing

Tags: jestjs, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test a component that loads data asynchronously when mounted. The component works as expected, it's just the test that's giving me issues. The component's `async loadData()` function hangs at `await axios.get()` while jest test runner is in the component.vm.$nextTick(). As a result, the checks in the $nextTick loop never pass.

Immediately after the $nextTick loop times out, the component's await statement completes and the component renders itself. axios is mocked, so it should resolve really fast. If I remove the await and just fill in a constant instead, the entire thing executes as expected.

I'm guessing that $nextTick loop is not asynchronous and it's consuming the thread, even though this is the recommended way of testing asynchronous stuff. The problem is, I don't have an onclick async handler to await: this method is called from onMount.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to make a jsFiddle of this one, so I hope this will be enough:

my component (the relevant parts)

```js
    export default {
      data() { return { content: '' }; },
      mounted() { this.loadDoc() }
      methods: {
        async loadDoc() {
          const res = await axios.get('some url'); // <-- this is the line that hangs until timeout
          // const res = { data: 'test data'}; // this would test just fine
          this.content = res.data;
        }
      }
    }
```

and my component.spec.js:

```js
    jest.mock('axios', () => ({
      get: async (url) => {
        return { data: 'test data' };
      }
    };

    describe('my super test', () => {
      it('renders', (done) => {
        const doc = shallowMount(myComponent);
        doc.vm.$nextTick(() => {
          expect(doc.html()).toContain('test data'); // <-- this never matches
          done();
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delete, but I just spent quite some hours for something that was suggested in the docs, but not explained that it's the only way... I'm hoping somebody else finds this useful.

Using `flush-promises` package instead of $nextTick loop immediately "fixed" the problem

Code sample (rework of above):

```javascript#
describe('my super test', () => {
  it('renders', async() => {
    const doc = shallowMount(myComponent);
    await flushPromises();
    expect(doc.html()).toContain('test data'); // <-- now it works
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it a way to access methods in tests? Like `doc.vm.loadDoc()`? Cause for me all the methods are `undefined` when there is a top-level await existed. I've made a question for that her: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74192860/16280429 
Will be appreciated for answering.